# How to loop through an array click by click(button) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to loop through an array that holds my colors. The program should display a new color in order, as the user clicks the next button. I just can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try. I know this is a dumb, I'm quite new to JavaScript.

```js
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow"]; /*Array to hold our colors*/

var i; /*iterative variable*/
var colorsLength = colors.length;

function iterate() {
  for (i of colors) {
    if((i<colorsLength) || (document.getElementById("forward").clicked = true)) {
      i++;
      document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }else{
      i = 0;
      document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body{
  height           : 100%;
  }
#banner {
  background-color : blue;
  padding-top      : 5%;
  padding-left     : 10%;
  height           : 30%;
  }
#buttons {
  margin-top       : 1em;
  padding-left     : 1em;
  }
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <h1> This is only the beginning... </h1>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <input id = "back"    type="button" value="previous" onclick="iterate()"/>
  <input id = "forward" type="button" value="next"     onclick="iterate(); return true;"/>
</div>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: unclear why you would be using a loop. Just add 1 to i. If it is greater than the length of your array reset to zero. Set the background color. You have the basic concept there, just get rid of the loop.

Comment: declare a variable e.g. var i = 0, increase and decrease it as per the click. and use it to access array value. colors[i].

Comment: @epascarello I was trying if it's possible to use a definite loop e.g. a for loop to sequentially iterate through my array using an iterative variable. I'll give your suggestion a try. Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
<div id="back" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <h1>color changes</h1>
</div>

<button onclick="move(-1)">prev</button>
<button onclick="move(1)">next</button>
```

in javascript

```
let colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow"];

let current = 0;
let back = document.getElementById("back")
back.style.backgroundColor = colors[0]
function move(dir){
  current += dir;
  if(current < 0) current = colors.length - 1;
  if(current === colors.length) current = 0;
  back.style.backgroundColor = colors[current]
}
```

it returns back to final or first color if it gets out of range.